# Unit testing using Mocha with Express Rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, tdd

I'm learning unit testing. So far I was able to run simple tests like "Add two numbers and test if they are above 0", but I want to build a REST API using TDD. So far I have this:

My `routes/index.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send({val: true});
});

module.exports = router;
```

My `index.test.js` file:

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var index = require('../routes/index');

describe('Index methods', () => {
    it('Returns true', done => {
        index
            .get('http://localhost:3000')
            .end(function (res) {
                expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                done();
            })
    })
});
```

I user a tutorial to do this, but when I try to run this I get:

```
TypeError: index.get(...).end is not a function
```

So I'm guessing there is something wrong, but have no idea what. That's my first day learning TDD so if you see anything stupid please let me know.

Doing this:

```
it('Returns true', done => {
    var resp = index.get('http://localhost:3000/');
    assert.equal(resp.val === true);
    done();
})
```

Also results in an error:

```
AssertionError: expected false to equal undefined
```

Comment: can you show the ../routes/index file?

Comment: It's the first file there

Comment: I think you are trying to make API request using supertest module check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Install the dev dependencies for mocha

- [chai](http://www.chaijs.com/): assertion library for node and browser,
- [chai-http](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http): HTTP Response assertions for the Chai Assertion Library.

### 2. You need to export your server,

```
'use strict';
/*eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["warn", "error", "log"] }] */
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//...
const config = require('config');

const port = process.env.PORT || config.PORT || 3000;

//....
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);

module.exports = app;
```

### 3. Write your tests as:

If your test script is **users.spec.js**,it should start by:

```js
// During the rest the en variable is set to test
/* global describe it beforeEach */
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const User = require('../app/models/user');

// Require the dev-dependencies
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

// You need to import your server
const server = require('../server');

const should = chai.should();
// Set up the chai Http assertion library
chai.use(chaiHttp);

// Your tests
describe('Users', () => {
    beforeEach((done) => {
        User.remove({}, (err) => {
            done();
        });
    });
    
    /**
     * Test the GET /api/users
     */
    describe('GET /api/users', () => {
        it('it should GET all the users', (done) => {
            chai.request(server)
                .get('/api/users')
                .end((err, res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.body.should.be.a('array');
                    res.body.length.should.be.eql(0);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
    // More test...
});
```

You can take a look at my repository, [Github - Book Store REST API](https://github.com/Lazhari/book-store)

Comment: So I have to pass my server file? (in my case `app.js`)? So how would I break it apart to have code in different files?

Comment: Yes, you need to export your server from app.js ``module.exports = app`` and then  import it on your index.test.js as ``const server = require('./app')``

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

first install chai

```
it('Returns true', done => {
            return chai.request(index)
                .get('/')
                .then(function (res) {
                    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                    done();
                })
        })
```

Comment: @alex.iron Are you using apply variable anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var index = require('./index');
var req = require('supertest');

describe('Index methods', () => {
    it('Returns true', done => {
        req(index)
            .get('/')
            .end(function (res) {
                expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                done();
            })
    })
});
```

also in your terminal type `npm i supertest --save-dev`

Comment: see updated ans. also you need to require your app instance in the file.

Comment: export you apps instance in the or whatever your entry point  is.

Answer (score 0):

simple test case to check if the server is running properly.

```
const chai = require('chai'),
chaiHttp = require('chai-http'),
server = require('../app'),
faker = require('faker'),
should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Init', function () {

it('check app status', function (done) {
  chai.request(server).get('/').end((err, res) => {
    should.not.exist(err);
    res.should.have.status(200);
    done();
  })
});

});
```

Test Cases for get API

```
describe('/Get API test', function () {

  it('Check the api without user id parameter', function (done) {
    chai.request(server).get('/post-list').end((err, res) => {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.should.have.status(401);
      res.body.should.be.a('object');
      res.body.should.have.property('message');
      res.body.should.have.property('message').eql('User Id parameter is missing');
      done();
    })
  });

  it('Check the api with user id. Success', function (done) {
    chai.request(server).get('/post-list?user_id=1').end((err, res) => {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.body.should.be.a('object');
      res.body.should.have.property('userId');
      res.body.should.have.property('title');
      res.body.should.have.property('body');
      done();
    })
  });

});
```

Test Case for Post API

```
describe('/POST API test', function () {

  it('Check the api without parameters . failure case', function (done) {
    chai.request(server).post('/submit-data').send({}).end((err, res) => {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.should.have.status(401);
      res.body.should.be.a('object');
      res.body.should.have.property('message');
      res.body.should.have.property('message').eql('Mandatory params are missing!');
      done();
    })
  });

  it('Check the API with valid parameters. Success', function (done) { 
    chai.request(server).post('/submit-data').send({name:faker.name.firstName(),email:faker.internet.email()}).end((err, res) => { 
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.body.should.be.a('object');
      res.body.should.have.property('message');
      res.body.should.have.property('message').eql('data saved successfully');
      done();
    })
  });

});
```

Add test cases as per the different case available in your API.

Find here the basic terminologies and complete sample application to proceed: https://medium.com/@pankaj.itdeveloper/basics-about-writing-tests-in-nodejs-api-application-4e17a1677834